# Is there a data structure with efficient inserts/deletes, but with positional ordering?

Tags: javascript, .net, data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure with efficient inserts, deletes and lookups, for which a binary tree would usually qualify, however my items are not ordered based on their value - rather I need them to be ordered based on their actual insert position (i.e. like an array). All operations will access, insert or delete items based on this position, as you would with an array.

- getItem(int position)
- addItem(int insertPosition, object item)
- removeItem(int position)

So basically the problem is that inserting/deleting an item causes all items after it to have their index shifted by 1. Clearly storing the index will never yield better than O(n), so basic binary trees/hash tables are out.

Is there a structure that's capable of implementing all these operations sub linear time? I keep thinking that a binary tree could be adapted somehow, and I'd support lookup by index by having each node store the number of nodes in it's left branch.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but why can't you use an array?

Comment: just use an object since you don't need to maintain indexing automatically. it will be faster than an Array, and much faster than hand-rolled fancy code.

Comment: @dandavis presumably, calling "addItem" at a particular position would shift the positions of all subsequent elements.

Comment: any reason not to just use a hash table with the positions as keys? (if this is in javascript that could just be a generic object).  If you need to shift the positions when adding in the middle I think you're out of luck on addItem being sub O(N) since it by definition will need to perform N/2 operations on average.

Comment: @ben336 I think that would work, except for being a little messy when you want to add or remove items

Comment: @pointy - the index is passed, so i assumed not... you have to pay the piper at some point. if you need auto-numbering, then yeah, use an array.

Comment: @dandavis,pointy shifting is by definition a linear task, so if thats a requirement I don't think he's going to be able to do what he wants here.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that inserting/deleting an item causes all items after it to have their index shifted by 1. Clearly storing the index will never yield better than O(n), so basic binary trees/hash tables are out.

Comment: @ben336 It is not by definition a linear task. Updating n explicitly stored indices would be, but I see no reason this should be the only way to implement insertion in the middle. I'll look around a bit.

Comment: @Trent Are you looking for a solution in JavaScript or ASP.NET? You tagged your question with both

Comment: JavaScript, but since it doesn't have much in the way of data structures, I'd settle for a .net solution that I could adapt to JS

Answer (score 0):

2-3 Finger Trees annotated with indices should be able to do this. They're persistent (in the functional programming sense), which may be good or bad. If you want a mutable variant badly enough, it's at least a source of ideas. 2-3 Finger Trees support

1. Logarithmic-time access, and
2. Adding and removing at beginning and end in amortized constant time, and
3. Splitting and concatenating in time logarithmic in the size of the smaller piece.

So to to insert at an arbitrary position, you can split at that position, add to the end of one of the parts, and then concatenate.
Similarly, to remove an item, you can split at that index, remove the item, and concatenate again. Both takes less than O(log n) time, and this is an over-approximation.

An existing implementation (special cased for index annotation, and tuned for performance) is the [`Data.Sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.2.1/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html) module in Haskell. The [paper](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/FingerTree.html) introducing them is harder to read than it needs to be. There is an [article](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/monoid-fingertree.html) which explains the general idea more clearly, but omits many details so it's not enough to *implement* them.

Answer (score -1):

List supports those features and is O(1) for add if the capacity > count

[List.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx)

Everything else is O(N) but in practice is better.
If you inset at position 0 then it is O(N) but if you inset at the second to last you will find it is better than O(N).

```
    List<simple> ls = new List<simple>();
    simple ss = new simple(0);
    ls.Add(ss);
    ls.Add(new simple(2));
    ls.Insert(0, new simple(1));
    ls.Add(new simple(3));
    ls.Add(new simple(4));
    ls.RemoveAt(2);
    foreach(simple s in ls) 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s.ID);
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ls[1].ID.ToString());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ls.IndexOf(ss).ToString());
}
public class simple
{
    public Int32 ID { get; private set; }
    public simple(Int32 id) { ID = id; }
}
```

Comment: -1 `List.Add` is efficient for adding at the end, but this question includes addition in the middle, which is linear time.

Comment: @delnan And that is reflected in the answer.

Comment: Great, but that doesn't change the fact that `List` is not an answer to this question.